# How build a generic (change) function in a child component to be used on diferents parents components? angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, input, output, angular9

I want to be able to build a "Generic" (change) function in a child component to be used for one or more parents with differents behavior.

I was trying to do something with the @input but the problem is that the event (change) I have to put directly in the child template. How can I place it in the Parent Template?

**child**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   selector: "select-state",
   template: `select  name=""  #selectstate >
                  <option selected > {{ selectStartMessage }}</option>
                   < option[value]="state.stateCode" * ngFor="let state of states" > {{ state.stateName }}</option>
              < /select>`,
   styleUrls: []
})

export class SelectState {


   @Input() callback: Function;

   constructor() { }
}
```

**Parent 1**

```
<section class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-11">
           <select-state (change)"FunctionParent1()"></select-state>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**Parent 2**

```
<section class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-11">
           <select-state (change)"FunctionParent2()"></select-state>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you sould use `@Ouput()` NOT `@Input`. Input is between `[` `]` and you need pass the function itselft: e.g. `[customFunction]="FunctionParent"` and use in children `this.customFunction()`

Comment: Yes, i was thinking to use the @output but.. the problem for me is make the event (change) generic to take to correct function for each parent